# springfox hide allowEmptyValue when field annotated with @ApiModelProperty

Tags: swagger-ui, springfox

How can I hide the `allowEmptyValue` description of response type on swagger-ui.html.

springfox version: 2.8.0

springfox-ui version: 2.8.0

[image: screenshot from swagger html]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a customized property builder plugin can help, try to set `allowEmptyValue` to `null`.

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BeanPropertyDefinition;
import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ModelPropertyBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.schema.ModelPropertyBuilderPlugin;
import springfox.documentation.spi.schema.contexts.ModelPropertyContext;

@Component
public class CustomizedModelPropertyBuilderPlugin implements ModelPropertyBuilderPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final DocumentationType arg0) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(final ModelPropertyContext context) {
        final ModelPropertyBuilder builder = context.getBuilder();

        final Optional<BeanPropertyDefinition> beanPropDef = context.getBeanPropertyDefinition();

        if (!beanPropDef.isPresent()) {
            return;
        }

        final BeanPropertyDefinition beanDef = beanPropDef.get();
        final AnnotatedMethod method = beanDef.getGetter();
        if (method == null) {
            return;
        }

        final ApiModelProperty apiModelProperty = method.getAnnotation(ApiModelProperty.class);
        if (apiModelProperty == null) {
            return;
        }

        builder.allowEmptyValue(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some update, it works! `beanPropDef.get();` it is a guava optional. Check if it is present first!

Comment: I used to get this error in the old spring-fox version 2.8.2, when I upgraded to 2.9.2 version, I am not seeing this text (allowedEmptyValue=false) anymore :). I didn't do any other config changes.