# Correcting Springfox setting allowEmptyValue on path parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have a method annotated with `@ApiParam` as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({LinksBuilder.BASE_URL})
@Api(tags = "Stuff Initiation", description="Stuff Initiation Service")
public class StuffResource {
    @ApiOperation(value = "some description", tags = "Stuff Initiation")
    @PostMapping(value = "/{stuffProduct}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Stuff InitiationResponse> postInitiateStuff (
            @ApiParam(required=true,value="Stuff initiation payload")
            @Valid @RequestBody Stuff Initiation stuffInitiation,
            @ApiParam(name="stuffProduct", required= true, allowableValues="productStuff1,productStuff2,productStuff3")
            @PathVariable String stuffProduct) throws StuffServiceException { ...  }
...
}
```

The issue is that the swagger document generated by springfox (2.9.2) has a `"allowEmptyValue":false` which is disallowed on a path parameter by the swagger standard.

In an attempt to remedy this, I have implemented a solution similar to [springfox hide allowEmptyValue when field annotated with @ApiModelProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379238/springfox-hide-allowemptyvalue-when-field-annotated-with-apimodelproperty):

```
package com.example.config;


import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.google.common.base.Optional;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.ParameterBuilderPlugin;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.ParameterContext;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.common.SwaggerPluginSupport;

@Component
@Order(SwaggerPluginSupport.SWAGGER_PLUGIN_ORDER + 100)
public class CustomizedParameterBuilderPlugin implements ParameterBuilderPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final DocumentationType arg0) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(ParameterContext context) {
        //Optional<ApiModelProperty> annotation = empty();

        Optional<ApiParam> apiParam = context.resolvedMethodParameter().findAnnotation(ApiParam.class);

        if (apiParam.isPresent()) {
            //apiParam.get().allowEmptyValue();

            context.parameterBuilder().allowEmptyValue(null);
            System.err.println(apiParam.get().name() + "\t" + apiParam.get().type());
        }
    }
}
```

I get the right elements, but apparently the setting of `context.parameterBuilder().allowEmptyValue(null);` doesn't work... the elements are still generated

I am aware that the root cause is a [known bug, and is set as status fixed](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2419), but I have not got the possibility of using 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT